# Postgresql Devart EF : The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, postgresql, transactions, entity-framework-6, devart

i got this exception when executing a simple read query using entity framework on our Postgre Db,
in the code, which throw this exception, i dont use transactions
the code do not fail systematically but randomly

this the stack trace :

```
{
  "Depth": 0,
  "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
  "Message": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
  "Source": "EntityFramework",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n  ......,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": {
    "Name": "Open",
    "AssemblyName": "EntityFramework",
    "AssemblyVersion": "6.0.0.0",
    "AssemblyCulture": "",
    "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection",
    "Signature": "Void Open()",
    "MemberType": 8
  },
  "HResult": -2146233087,
  "HelpURL": null
},
{
  "Depth": 1,
  "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "Message": "The current TransactionScope is already complete.",
  "Source": "System.Transactions",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()\r\n   at Devart.Common.DbConnectionFactory.a(DbConnectionBase A_0)\r\n   at Devart.Common.DbConnectionFactory.b(DbConnectionBase A_0)\r\n   at Devart.Common.DbConnectionClosed.Open(DbConnectionBase outerConnection)\r\n   at Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Open()\r\n   at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": {
    "Name": "get_Current",
    "AssemblyName": "System.Transactions",
    "AssemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
    "AssemblyCulture": "",
    "ClassName": "System.Transactions.Transaction",
    "Signature": "System.Transactions.Transaction get_Current()",
    "MemberType": 8
  },
  "HResult": -2146233079,
  "HelpURL": null
}
```

in the Db the transaction are enabled, 
i set the `max_prepared_transactions = max_connections =100`

i m using Devart provider with EF for a Postgresql database

any idea why/when this exception happen ?

Comment: We use Devart's libs and they're pretty reliable normally. Obviously, something's getting upset in your case. What do your connection strings look like? And what does the code look like where you create the db context?

Comment: the connection string is :
User Id=******;Password=******;Host=myHost;Database=myDb;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Schema=myInitialSchema;Port=5432;Unicode=True

he dbContext is contructed is :
public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
....
        }

Comment: 1. Please send us a working project (as simple as it can be) and specify the exact steps we should follow for reproducing the error: https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html .

2. Tell us an approximate time to wait for the error to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem fixed by setting `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` when creating the transactionscope

https://particular.net/blog/transactionscope-and-async-await-be-one-with-the-flow